# Magento search broken. Gives fatal error if nothing is found

Tags: php, magento, search, fatal-error

When searched for an empty string or anything that is not found on the website, Magento gives a fatal error like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on a non-object in /www/sites/www.xyz.com/files/html/app/code/local/Abc/Search/Block/View.php on line 39
```

I have reindexed the data and deleted the cache. Nothing works.

---

Here is sample code: it begins with line 39.

```
   foreach($this->getChild('activity_filter')->getItems() as $item):
     if($item->getCount() > 0):
        array_push($activityLabels, $item->getLabel());
     endif;
   endforeach;
```

---

**Update:** We have setup a staging environment with exactly the same code. The search works on the staging environment, but doesn't work on the production site.

Comment: Please add your Magento version number. Have you installed any modules that affect the search?

Comment: It is magento 1.8. And Search is a custom module.

Comment: Sounds like your module is broken. As it's a custom module it is very unlikely that you can get a fix here without showing your code.

Comment: I have added the code above, could you please have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've got a module installed called Abc/Search that is causing the problem. Try disabling that module in the config xml and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: And check back with the third party developer that produced the module. They will either have had to fix this for their customers or will have a module upgrade you need to install to fix it.